# nginx : upstream with multiple server directives?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to package 2 applications that use nginx as a proxy and deliver each a config file into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`.

Doing this in one file (`combined.conf`) works great :

```
    upstream backend1 {
      http://localhost:8989;
    }

    upstream backend2 {
      http://localhost:8990;
    }

    server {
      location /backend1/ {
        proxy_pass  http://backend1;
      }
      location /backend2/ {
        proxy_pass  http://backend2;
      }
```

However, when splitting into 2 files, one of the redirects fails systematically:

- `backend1.conf`:

  ```
  upstream backend1 {
    http://localhost:8989;
  }

  server {
    location /backend1/ {
      proxy_pass  http://backend1;
    }
  ```
- `backend2.conf`:

  ```
  upstream backend2 {
    http://localhost:8990;
  }

  server {
    location /backend2/ {
      proxy_pass  http://backend2;
    }
  ```

So my question is : can an `http` node have 2 different `server` childs ?

Nginx [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server) says nothing about it.

Other people seem to have [succeeded](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-nginx-namebased-virtual-hosting-configuration/) with this kind of architecture though :(

Nginx version is 1.1.19-1ubuntu0.1.

Thanks for any advice !

Comment: To be more precise, when I use the 2 files approach it is the default site that answers with a 404.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after so rumbling & testing, I figured a way to make it work and be able to ship one config file per application.

Here it is, dispatched in one common file and a pair of upstream/location files per application:

- `/etc/nginx/conf.d/common-proxies.conf`:

  ```
  include /upstreams/*.conf;

  server {
  include /locations/*.conf
  }
  ```
- `/etc/nginx/locations/backend1.conf`

  ```
  location /backend1/ {
    upstream http://backend1;
  }
  ```
- `/etc/nginx/locations/backend2.conf`

  ```
  location /backend2/ {
    upstream http://backend2;
  }
  ```
- `/etc/nginx/upstreams/backend1.conf`

  ```
  upstream backend1 {
    http://localhost:8989;
  }
  ```
- `/etc/nginx/upstreams/backend2.conf`

  ```
  upstream backend2 {
    http://localhost:8990;
  }
  ```

Comment: Is this a typo? upstream should have "server localhost:8990" instead of "http://localhost:8990;". See here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: It seems from the doc you linked that every command inside a block is ended by a semi column. E.g. `upstream backend { server 127.0.0.1:8080       max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s; }`. Also, this works with the `;` :)

Comment: I meant that the keyword 'server' is missing before the address. Ignore the semicolon part.

Answer (score 1):

A http block can have many server children. However, nginx selects one server block to process a request.  So, the request never 'sees' the backend2 location because it matches against the first server block.

Comment: You mean probably it is my `location` directive that sucks and grab the request intended for backend2 ?

Comment: Or is it that I need a way to differentiate both `server` blocks when nginx looks for the appropriate `server` to forward the request ?

Comment: Both location blocks should be within the same server block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one such solution that works for me with basic authentication.

Install required packages to generate passwords using htpasswd

```
sudo yum install httpd-tools        [RHEL/CentOS]
sudo apt install apache2-utils      [Debian/Ubuntu]
```

create password files with below commands

```
htpasswd -c /home/osboxes/nginx1-auth.htpasswd  admin
htpasswd -c /home/osboxes/nginx2-auth.htpasswd  sysadmin
htpasswd -c /home/osboxes/glances-auth.htpasswd devopsadmin
```

nginx.conf file

```
    ###############Start-of-Nginx-Config-file #########
    
    events {}
    
    http {
    upstream backend_nginx1 {
        server nginx1;
    }
    upstream backend_nginx2 {
        server nginx2;
    }
    
    upstream backend_glances {
        server glances:61208;
    }
    
    
    
    server {
        listen 7070;
        server_name _;
        location / {
            #//turn on auth for this location
            auth_basic "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/nginx1-auth.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://backend_nginx1;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name _;
        location / {
            #//turn on auth for this location
            auth_basic "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/nginx2-auth.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://backend_nginx2;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 9090;
        server_name _;
        location / {
            #//turn on auth for this location
            auth_basic "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/glances-auth.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://backend_glances;
        }
    }
    
    
    }
#Proxy on nginx tcp port
stream {
  upstream postgres {
    server pdb3:5432;
  }
  server {
    listen 5432;
    proxy_pass postgres;
  }
}
```

Now deploying backend docker containers to be served by front-end nginx load-balancer

```
sudo docker run -d  --name nginx1  nginx

sudo docker run -d  --name nginx2  nginx
```

Glances container is a combination of top/htop for getting system/docker resources on console or on web browser.

```
sudo docker run -d --restart="always"  -e GLANCES_OPT="-w" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro --pid host --name glances docker.io/nicolargo/glances
```

Deploying Front-end nginx load-balancer to serve backend services/containers

```
sudo docker run -d --name nginx-reverseProxy  -p 7070:7070 -p 8080:8080 -p 9090:9090 --link nginx1:nginx1 --link nginx2:nginx2 --link glances:glances -v /home/osboxes/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -v  /home/osboxes/nginx1-auth.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/nginx1-auth.htpasswd  -v /home/osboxes/nginx2-auth.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/nginx2-auth.htpasswd -v /home/osboxes/glances-auth.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/glances-auth.htpasswd  nginx
```